# Write file inside filter servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets

I'm trying to write a `log.txt` file from a filter. I put the file in `WEB-INF` (`WEB-INF/logs.txt`). The filter is executed after each log in. The code is:

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String relpath = this.config.getInitParameter("Archivo");
String fullpath = this.config.getServletContext().getRealPath(relpath);

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fullpath);
OutputStreamWriter outStream = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

// The write have some vars defined before...
outStream.write(remoteAddress + " | " + date + " | " + method + "\n");
outStream.close();

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

The app does not fail when is executed, but the file is not written. Any ideas?

Comment: The likely case is that, if the file is being created on the system successfully, every time this code path is traversed, you're trampling on the previous entries (since you don't use the [alternate constructor for `FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).  I'd also strongly discourage trying to use a homebrew solution to write logs and look into Log4J2 or Logback instead, as those are far easier to configure and use.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import java.util.*;

  // Implements Filter class
  public class LogFilter implements Filter  {
 public void  init(FilterConfig config) 
                     throws ServletException{
  // Get init parameter 
  String testParam = config.getInitParameter("test-param"); 

  //Print the init parameter 
    System.out.println("Test Param: " + testParam); 
  }
   public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
             ServletResponse response,
             FilterChain chain) 
             throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

   // Get the IP address of client machine.   
   String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

   // Log the IP address and current timestamp.
    System.out.println("IP "+ ipAddress + ", Time "
                                   + new Date().toString());

    // Pass request back down the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request,response);
  }
   public void destroy( ){
    /* Called before the Filter instance is removed 
    from service by the web container*/
     }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   this is web.xml

   <filter>
  <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>LogFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
  <param-name>test-param</param-name>
  <param-value>Initialization Paramter</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```